# What is Time Complexity of the following function?

Tags: performance, algorithm, functional-programming, time-complexity

```
int DoSomething(int n) {
    if(n < 2) return 1;
    else return DoSomething(floor(sqrt(n))) + n;
}
```

According to me the corresponding recurrence will be :

[image: Recurence Relatio]

Solving this recurence...

Putting [image: Substitute 1]

The function becomes

[image: Rest of the image]

Can you please verify & rectify the solution?

Answer (score 2):

**you are correct upto** :-

```
S(m) = O(log(m))
```

**then**

```
T(2^m) = O(log(m))

n = 2^m

T(n) = O(log(m))

but m = log(n)

hence 

T(n) = log(log(n))
```

Comment: How come this,please make me understand--->`S(m) = O(log(m))
then S(2^m) = O(log(m))`... I believe that OP is correct. Please correct me too if I am wrong!

Comment: @shekharsuman Yes i still disagree check my comment. Moreover consider that you recurrence relation is correct still you answer is wrong  if f(n) = logn then T(n) cannot be O(log(logn)) because the latter is asymtotically smaller than f(n) . T(n) must atleast be O(logn). Do you disgree on this even , then you must read time complexity analysis again.

Comment: @VikramBhat Complexity of addition is IMO O(log(n)) because it depends on the number of bits in n.

Comment: @user1990169 that is true for arbitary long data but in the above function int data type is used for which addition is O(1) iterations. In general your observation is correct but not for that above case

Comment: @VikramBhat Complexity calculation is in general done for the algorithm and not code. We should not put a limit because of the data type used. My earlier question was based on the fact that the first term has a very small value wrt n, so the time consumed in an addition operation becomes significant for arbitrarily large n.

Comment: @user1990169 In that case every algorithm needs to be revised because every algorithm has addition or comparison in it. For example we might argue that binary search is O((logn)^2) because the comparison that we do in it is O(logn) for arbitrary long integers. These sort of generalization is avoided on input because when you use it in practice we get ratios of run time as logn1/logn2 not (logn1/logn2)^2 because the 32-bit processor can evaluate comparision on integer in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is wrong at the very first step !

Now,going through your steps, your recurrence equation is wrong.

The recurrence will be of the form--->`T(n) = a ⋅ T(n / b) + f(n)`,here, a=1,b=2, and f(n)=log n(because n is getting stored successively in stack and it is decrementing each time by half, whereas you have assumed f(n) as 1   **//  THIS IS THE SOURCE OF ERROR!**

`T(2^m)=T(2^(m/2))+m`   //  Improve your steps.

`S(m)=S(m/2)+log m`    // Improve your steps

On solving this equation using `master theorem`---it'll come under second formula of master theorem as

**f(n) ~= log n ~= 1 == 0(n^log 2 (1)) == 0(n^0) ==1**   // ,most important step,if unclear,please ask...

, you'll get solution as `0(log (m)).`

`S(m) = O(log m)`

Next, on raising to the power, `T(2^(m))=O(log m)` which will further yield

Now,substituting the value of m as `(m=log 2 (n))` back in this equation, you'll get

`T(n)=O(log ( log (n)))`.

I hope this is much clear.Feel free to comment if you couldn't understand any step...

Comment: Hey,wait---did you notice that there is a factor n being added to stack because of the statement `return DoSomething(floor(sqrt(n))) + n;`! So, I have given the general solution. Next, master theorem can be applied as `log n` is treated as a constant OR 1! Where I am wrong!

Comment: Also,here addition is not considered a factor,but,rather the factor by which your n is diminishing is important. Your point is invalid, I think you again need a downvote.

Comment: See, I am really not here for upvote OR downvote. No matter how much downvotes I receive,you must acknowledge that the point you mentioned of addition taking constant time is invalid. It has to work my way in terms of changing of `n`! You must acknowledge this,else provide with a proof ...

Comment: I'll surely be happy simply with a link as proof and I'll guaranteedly upvote you. It's not like revenge or blackmailing---I just want that OP must get correct answer. That's it,please provide me with the link,I'll happily and gladly appreciate your effort and delete all of my comments! THANKS in advance.

Comment: Here, the issue is not at all associated with addition operation---obviously it takes O(1) operations. But, you must acknowledge that n is getting halved each time in recursion and that's what will come to effect. The process of n getting halved will result in `log n` coming into picture. DO you still disagree!!!

Comment: firstly n is not getting halved in every iteration it is square root , it is the no of bits of n that are getting halved. Moreover f(n) that is used in recurrence relation is amount of work done in one recursion that is only sqrt(n) and + which are O(1) , logn doesnt even come into picture here.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking wrongly about f(n). I confused myself about addition of n. Thanks for improving me. I am removing my downvote and comments and rather upvoting your's . Also, I won't request for upvote as I am editing my answer! THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on such a methodology to solve it:

[image]